# Resultant Matrix for Transforming a Polynomial with roots that are Reciprocals

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

As described in [this Brilliant article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/transforming-roots-of-polynomial/), it is possible to represent polynomial transformations using a Resultant. However, the example provided at the bottom of the page, and all examples provided in treatments of polynomial transformations that I've seen, regard functions in one variable for the relationship that roots in the resulting polynomial must satisfy. In particular, to quote the article linked above,

> Suppose $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$ is a rational functions with $g$ and $h$ polynomials. Given a polynomial $P$ with roots $r_i$, the way to construct the polynomial $Q$ with roots $f(r_i)$ is as follows: the roots of $Q$ are $y_i = \frac{g(r_i)}{h(r_i)}$, so they are solutions $y_i$ to the two-variable system of equations
> $$yh(x) - g(x) = 0 $$
> $$P(x) = 0.$$
> The monic polynomial with these roots is (up to a scaling factor) the resultant $\text{Res}_x (yh(x) - g(x), P(x)).$

But the rational function $f(x)$ is of one variable! My question is how we can apply the Resultant in the case where $f(x)$ is a function of, say, two roots.

For concreteness sake, suppose we are dealing with a cubic whose roots are $r_1, r_2, r_3$ and we want to find a polynomial whose roots are $\frac{r_1}{r_2}, \frac{r_2}{r_3}, \frac{r_3}{r_1}.$ How can we apply the Resultant here?

I decided to work this out for a simple case for a quadratic. So, given the polynomial $x^2 - 3x -4$, the polynomial that satisfies the requested transformation becomes $4x^2 + 17x+4.$ It's not difficult to prove, using Vieta's formulas, that given the more general situation with a given polynomial $a_1x^2 + b_1x + c_1$ with roots $r_1, r_2$, the polynomial whose roots are $\frac{r_1}{r_2}, \frac{r_2}{r_1}$ given by $a_2x^2 + b_2x + c_2$ satisfies the following relations: $c_2 = a_2$ and $\frac{-b_2}{a_2} = \frac{b_1^2}{a_1c_1} -2.$ But the process using Vieta's formulas would get pretty tedious for higher degrees, and plus the connection to the Resultant is not at all evident for me. Could you please help me? If possible, I would appreciate if someone could work through the case for a third degree polynomial, but a hint or reference to reading material would be greatly appreciated anyway.

Comment: You complain about them using a function of one variable, but in your discussion and examples, you only talk about functions of one variable yourself. I really don't understand what your issue is. If you know the roots $y_i$ of a polynomial (with roots of multiplicity $k$ represented by $k$ distinct indices), then the monic polynomial with those roots is $(x- y_1)(x-y_2)\ldots(x-y_n)$.

Comment: In your specific cubic e,g, you aren't even talking about a symmetric transformation of the roots.  Hence you will not get a unique cubic anyway as answer, the transformed cubic will depend on your choice of ordering the roots.  The quadratic case thankfully is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you, yes this was a flawed question, I should have thought more about it at first.